# ffmpeg subtitle background

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to add subtitles to a video in marathi language and to make it user friendly i have added a background to subtitle however there are some black lines coming in the background. Please help me in removing those lines.

```
ffmpeg -i output_mp4.mp4 -vf "subtitles=transcript_srt.srt: force_style='OutlineColour=&H80000000,BorderStyle=3,Outline=1,Shadow=1'" -c:a copy output_srt.mp4
```

This is the command i have used.

[image]

Comment: Change BorderStyle to 4.

Comment: Hi Gyan, thanks for your comment, it worked :)